# reading csv file python 3.6 using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, datetime

I am reading a huge csv file in Python using the read_csv method of Pandas. I have a column that has dates and time (both in the same column) of the format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. I is the 0th column of the data. Currently what I am doing is:

```
    format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    parser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, format)
    data = pd.read_csv("path/to/file", sep=',', encoding='ISO-8859-1', parse_dates=[0], date_parser=parser)
```

But it tells me to use specify dtype option on import. I tried adding an argument to the call: `dtype = {[0]:pandas.datetime}` but it didn't work. Do you have a better workaround this? Or can someone explain how to use the dtype argument properly? I tried reading the documentation but didn't help much.

Comment: Can you post the actual errors you are getting?

Comment: Try without the `date_parser` arg. Pandas has a good default for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to format the column after reading the file

```
data = pd.read_csv("path/to/file", sep=',', encoding='ISO-8859-1')

data[0] = pd.to_datetime(data[0], format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Hope it helps.